# Show data in chat emulator bot framework

Tags: botframework

I need to display lot of data in my chat. I want to display it in tabular form in chat emulator of bot framework.

For eg,

Ordered Food - Pizza
Quantity - 1
Time - 1 pm

Ordered Food -Burger
Quantity - 2
Time - 3pm

I want to display it in tabular way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [docs](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/activities.html#textformat), the default text format for the messages is markdown. Markdown allows a nice balance of the bot being able to express what they want and for the each channel to render as accurately as they can.

The [AzureBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBot/blob/master/AzureBot.Services.Runbooks/Dialogs/AutomationDialog.cs#L245-L260) is crafting a table using markdown:

```
var messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
messageBuilder.AppendLine("|Id|Runbook|Start Time|End Time|Status|");
messageBuilder.AppendLine("|---|---|---|---|---|");
   //...
messageBuilder.AppendLine($"|{job.FriendlyJobId}|{automationJob.RunbookName}|{startDateTime}|{endDateTime}|{status}|");

await context.PostAsync(messageBuilder.ToString());
```

Alternatively, you can try sending the text along with the `\t` character code, like:

```
await context.PostAsync("test1\t\ttest2");
```