# How to represent data in nice table format in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, string.format

I've written following code to display the data

```
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
result += "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
result += "Product Name\t|\tCost Price\t|\tSold Quantity\t|\tSales Amount\t|\tNet Amount\t|\tProfit\t|\tSale Date\n\n";
result += "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
while (reader.Read())
{
        result += String.Format("{0}\t|\t{1}\t|\t{2}\t|\t{3}\t|\t{4}\t|\t{5}\t|\t{6:d}\n\n", reader[0], reader[1], reader[2], reader[3], reader[4], reader[5], reader[6]);
}
        result += "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
reader.Close();
```

And, it displays the data as:

[image]

How can I improve it to display properly?

Comment: Why don't you use datagridView or any other control for this purpose?

Comment: What does "improve" mean to you? Can you be more specific? Have a look at all the different format strings for [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Comment: I want data as string to send it to display on chat bot in Microsoft Bot Framework. And to "improve" means, I want it to look like a table so that each string should appear as if in a cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630617/show-data-in-chat-emulator-bot-framewok/40632357#40632357

Answer (score 3):

I assume that this is a console application, so a datagrid is not possible.

So you need to work out the size of each field, and then for the appropriate data you need to pad out the string to the right length.

Depending on the datatype, you might want to pad left or right.

To help you you can use the;

```
String.PadLeft
String.PadRight
```

Microsoft website has more details on this;  [Padding Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is an example, you might have to adjust slightly for your code.

```
 string[] fields = new string[] { "Product Name", "Cost Price", "Sold Quantity", "Sales Amount", "Net Amount", " Profit", "Sale Date" };

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string fieldSeperator = "\t|";
    foreach (String h in fields)
        sb.Append(h + fieldSeperator);

    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        foreach(string fieldName in fields)
        {
            switch (fieldName)
            {
                case "Product Name":    sb.Append(reader[0].PadRight(fieldName.Length));
                    break;
                case "Cost Price":      sb.Append(reader[1].PadRight(fieldName.Length));
                    break;
                case "Sold Quantity":   sb.Append(reader[2].PadRight(fieldName.Length));
                    break;
                case "Sales Amount":    sb.Append(reader[3].PadRight(fieldName.Length));
                    break;
                case "Net Amount":      sb.Append(reader[4].PadRight(fieldName.Length));
                    break;
                case " Profit":          sb.Append(reader[5].PadRight(fieldName.Length));
                    break;
                case "Sale Date":       sb.Append(reader[6].PadRight(fieldName.Length));
                    break;

            }                    
            sb.Append(fieldSeperator);                    
        }
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    result = sb.ToString();
```

Note that I used a StringBuilder, as this would be better.

This assumes that your field names are longer or the same size as your data.  If this is not the case as happens in your "profit" field then this would throw out the formatting slightly.  So in this case I have added an extra space at the front of the field name, which I also need in the switch statement.

Comment: It works fine on console window but doesn't render on bot framework