# Return a table in microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework

I have created a form and sent the request to web api and got the response in json. i want to print the response in the form of table in bot.

```
String json = //api response
```

Can i convert the dtring to html table and display it?
 I tried formatting string and displaying it but it doesn't work.
Is there any better way to respond with table data?

like: Name | Age | PhoneNo \n 
      jhbg | 20  | 7787908080

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show data in chat emulator bot framewok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630617/show-data-in-chat-emulator-bot-framewok)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not; each channel has limited message display capabilities - you can use basic markdown in some channels but not others, for example.

I've seen one bot implementation use dynamic images as card attachments as a solution to this requirement though; check the SkyScanner chatbot - the flight times in a carousel are images: https://www.skyscanner.net/news/tools/skyscanner-facebook-messenger-bot/

Demo of rich media cards:
https://www.robinosborne.co.uk/2016/07/18/rich-botframework-conversation-cards/

Rich card documentation:
https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html